# ListView: each row associated with a different webservice

Tags: android, performance, listview

I'm using a listView in my app where every every row of listview gets its data from a different webservice. Currently, I'm doing this in the following fashion:

```
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
         ViewHolder viewHolder;
          ...
          ... 
          DownloadData downloadData = new DownloadData(viewHolder); 
          downloadData.execute();
          return convertView;
     }

    class DownloadData extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> //Downloads and update viewHolder
    {
     .....
    }
```

It runs perfectly.
However, I feel this isn't a good design since threading isn't supposed to be done inside an adapter. Is there a better approach to this ?

P.S: There is a constraint on my webservice and I can't alter it to solve this issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You definitely **do not** want to be doing this in `getView()`. `getView()` is really just responsible for turning some objects into views, it's not responsible for getting your data.

I would make sure I had all the data I needed before or even during population of the listview.

In other words, outside this adapter why don't you call all your async methods and have them return the right objects to pass into the adapter?

You can wait till they are all done, or call them in parallel and update the adapter as each one finishes, and call `notifyDatasetChanged()`.

Comment: I tried doing this earlier. However, I felt that even this approach had a constraint that there would be too many calls to `notifyDataSetChanged()` thereby affecting performance. What is your opinion ?

Comment: I've not noticed any performance issues with calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` a lot - ultimately if your view changes...your view changes and it needs updating :)

Comment: One more question: calling notifyDataSetChanged() would scroll listView everytime all the way to top. Then probably I had to apply a workaround to that.

Would it better to update just the particular row using `getChildAt` or calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` altogether ?

Comment: Uh, in my experience it doesn't scroll it all the way to the top, that only happens if I set a new adapter. By the way I also never call it outside the adapter. In the adapter, when you add an item or add all the items, after that, call `notifyDatasetChanged()`.